# Having trouble with inserting nodes in a sorted fashion

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes, singly-linked-list

I have a linked list that I have to insert objects into, based on one of the fields of the object I must insert nodes into the linked list in correct order.

I have had the sort working perfectly when using arrays and vectors but am having trouble simply with the insertion aspect of the linked list. my getLink() call is for a function that gets my link which is = next.

```
void sortedInsert(DomNodePtr& head, string fName, string lName, float CGPA, int rScore,string prov){
     DomNodePtr here = head;
     DomNodePtr tempPtr;
     tempPtr = new DomNode(fName, lName, CGPA, rScore, prov, head);

     while (here->getCumGPA() > CGPA && here->getLink() != NULL){
     here = here->getLink();

     }
     if (here->getCumGPA() < CGPA){
         tempPtr->setLink(here->getLink());
         here->setLink(tempPtr);
     }
     else if (here->getCumGPA() > CGPA){
         here = tempPtr;
     }
}
```

Basically I want the students with the highest Cumulative GPA to be sorted higher than the ones with lower CGPA.  I know part of my problem is I do not insert the students with lower CGPAs but I am struggling with that part.  It also is outputting about 10 students when I print the linked list when in fact their are about 100 and they are not in correct order.

Comment: Indenting your code would be the first essential step.

Comment: @n.m. my apologies for the poor formatting, I have fixed that.

Comment: You really should have started out simple instead of this.  Can you build a linked list of simple `int` that is sorted?  If you can, then replace `int` with your class, as the code would be virtually the same.  If you can't implement it for a linked list of `int`, there is little chance you're going to wade through trying to do this for a more complex type.

Comment: Try and find a small example that fails, i.e. two or three students at most. It's difficult to work out what's going wrong when you have 100 students. Then either use a debugger or even pencil and paper to trace through exactly what your code is doing with the links. Hopefully it will then become obvious where the bug is.

Comment: @john thank you very much for the feedback, you rock! This is actually what I did to work it out. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When inserting the new student to the list there are three cases:

- The CGPA for the new element is smaller than the CPGA values of all elemnts in the list. In this case the student has to be attached to the end of the list.
- The student has a CPGA larger than all elements of the list: The new element has to be added at the head of the list
- The student has a CPGA between two existing elements. Here the new element has to be inserted between those to elements. Therefor, you have to keep track of the previous element which has a CPGA larger than the CPGA of the new element.

  ```
  void sortedInsert(DomNodePtr& head, string fName, string lName, float CGPA, int rScore,string prov){
      DomNodePtr here = head;
      DomNodePtr tempPtr;
      tempPtr = new DomNode(fName, lName, CGPA, rScore, prov, head);

      DomNodePtr previous = NULL; // keeping track of the previous element

      while (here->getCumGPA() >= CGPA && here->getLink() != NULL){
          previous = here;
          here = here->getLink();
      }
      if (here->getLink() == NULL){
          // Insert new student at the end of the list
          // If CPGA is larger for all students in the list

          here->setLink(tempPtr);
      }
      else if (previous = NULL) {
          // The new student has the highest CGPA and
          // has to be added at the head of the list
          tempPtr->setLink(here);
      }
      else{
          // Insert the student between the current
          // and the previous elements of the list

          previous->setLink(tempPtr);
          tempPtr->setLink(here);
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Thank you very much, I had actually just figured it out but I do appreciate the feed back.  I would upvote if I could!

Comment: @kiotzu there is a neat trick you can do with a pointer to a pointer that eliminates the need to track the `previous` and `tempPtr` nodes. Rather than keeping track of the `here` node, you track a pointer to the `next` of the previous node, a `DomNodePtr  *`. This simultaneously gives you the insertion point, the node you wish to test, AND hides the one difference between `head` and any other `next` pointer. This can eliminate quite a bit of code because some of the cases you currently have to track are no longer required.

Comment: @user45813015 thank you for that! I will make sure to keep that in mind.